# Why is the asyncQueue processed before watchers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation in my AngularJS-based app where the visibility of element A results in element B being bigger or smaller in width (just due to how the element CSS styles are set up). The visibility of element A is toggled by binding to a boolean on the scope using `ng-show="showRail"`. For reasons I don't need to go into here, when the visibility of element A is toggled, I need to get element B's new width. If I use `$timeout` to evaluate element B's width I get an accurate reading but it's too late (the next frame) and causes a flicker due to some rendering that must be done as a result.  I understand that `$evalAsync` is intended to be best for executing some logic after the DOM has been updated but before the browser has rendered. So on the handler where I'm toggling the `showRail` boolean I'm running a `scope.$evalAsync` but it appears it's too early and element B has still not received its new width.

I went searching through Angular's $digest method and found that the [asyncQueue is processed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a001a417d5c12bad0fa09c88e045622b95239e2f/src/ng/rootScope.js#L686) before [watchers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a001a417d5c12bad0fa09c88e045622b95239e2f/src/ng/rootScope.js#L699). This seems backward to me and seems to explain why element A's visibility hasn't changed before I try to retrieve element B's new width. I'm hoping someone can explain why this is the case and maybe it will lead me to a solution to my specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: Even though it's private, but is the $$postDigest the thing you want?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I ended up going this route to fix my specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at setImmediate:

https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate

It's almost tailor-made for this kind of thing. There's nothing in Angular's core that lets you control the order in which these operations are performed, and the answer to "why" isn't going to help you solve your problem. But setImmediate can help you avoid the flicker and could be a 5-minute solution if it works...